# Find repository names from gitolite info output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, regular-expression, git

How do I extract the names from the gitolite `info` command output, for further piping into a script?

I'm writing a migration script to migrate all my repositories from gitolite to a Gitlab server. Thus, I want to get all the repository names from gitolite and use those in Gitlab. Below is [the example output](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/info_expand.html) I'm trying to match against.

```
hello sitaram, this is gitolite v2.1-29-g5a125fa running on git 1.7.4.4
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R      SecureBrowse
     R   W  anu-wsd
     R   W  entrans
    @R   W  git-notes
    @R   W  gitolite
     R   W  gitolite-admin
     R   W  indic_web_input
 @C  R   W  private/sitaram/[\w.-]+
     R   W  proxy
 @C @R   W  public/sitaram/[\w.-]+
    @R_ @W_ testing
     R   W  vic
```

This should output:

```
SecureBrowse
anu-wsd
entrans
git-notes
gitolite
gitolite-admin
indic_web_input
proxy
testing
vkc
```

Currently I'm trying to put this in a shell script, so it would be usable for others. My current approach is a `grep` command, which looks like the following:

```
grep -Eio "([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$" gitolite-info-output
```

However, this also captures the `4` at the end of the first line. I've been trying several approaches, but I can't seem to exclude that properly, without including or excluding other things.

Doing this *OS X 10.10.3*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the input you show in your question, this should work:

```
$ grep -oP '^[ @]*R.* \K.*' gitolite-info-output
SecureBrowse
anu-wsd
entrans
git-notes
gitolite
gitolite-admin
indic_web_input
proxy
testing
vic
```

This is using GNU grep's `-P` switch to enable Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which give us `\K` : "Exclude anything matched up to this point". Combined with `-o`, we can search for lines starting with 0 or more spaces or `@` (`^[ @]*`), then an `R`, then 0 or more characters until another space. All this is discarded because of the `\K` so only the last word is printed.

---

If you don't have GNU `grep` (on OSX, for example), you can do something like this:

```
$ grep -E '^[ @]*R' gitolite-info-output | awk '{print $NF}'
SecureBrowse
anu-wsd
entrans
git-notes
gitolite
gitolite-admin
indic_web_input
proxy
testing
vic
```

Or do the whole thing in `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^[ @]*R/{print $NF}' gitolite-info-output 
SecureBrowse
anu-wsd
entrans
git-notes
gitolite
gitolite-admin
indic_web_input
proxy
testing
vic
```

Or Perl:

```
$ perl -nle '/^[ @]*R.*\s(.*)/ && print $1' gitolite-info-output 
SecureBrowse
anu-wsd
entrans
git-notes
gitolite
gitolite-admin
indic_web_input
proxy
testing
vic
```

Comment: Well, this is awesome. Sadly I can't give you multiple up-votes. For every time you added another correct answer :) You were constantly beating my comments with more helpful edits. Thanks!